# Kerberos between IIS and SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, iis, kerberos

Let's say I have computer SQLCOMP with MSSqlServer running under a local account (.\sqllocuser).

I have another computer IISCOMP, with an IIS application (running under a domain account MYDOM\IISUSER).

The two servers are on the same domain. Can the IIS app connect into SQLServer using Kerberos?

If it is possible, which configuration I need to set?

Which SPNs I need? In particular which SPNs should be created for the MSSQLServer runnning under a local account? One related to the host (like when running under Network Services)?

Comment: Does it have to be Kerberos? Why isn't NTLM sufficient?

Comment: Question is for educational purposes. I was wondering if the "computer account" (the one that is used for SPN when SQLServer service runs within the built-in Network Service or LocalSystem accounts) was the one that needs to be setup when SQLServer runs under a local account.

Comment: No. The computer account can only be set up when running as NetworkService or LocalSystem. With SQL Server 2012 you can also use [Managed Service Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560633(v=ws.10).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible.

The SPN you set up needs to be mapped to the Windows Domain Account that starts SQL Server, hence you can't use a local account.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc280745%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Documentation is clear when SQLServer runs under a Domain Account or a built-in account like Network Service. But it says nothing (or I'm not able to find anything) for the case the SQLServer service runs under a local account...